# When did javascript start binding this to the object?

Tags: javascript

I am quite confused, as my knowledge of javascript seem to have been outdated. I remember that the following:

```
p = {
    foo: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

would have `this` not bound unless you used `new` to create a new instance with the object as prototype. Has this changed in recent years? It's been a very long time since I stopped coding in vanilla js so I might be wrong, or mixing different concepts together.

Comment: JS can't suddenly make a change like this without breaking a lot of stuff.

Comment: Your example will not bind `this`. The value of `this` will be determined by how the function is called. Can you give some more details about what you're seeing happen when you call it?

Comment: @NicholasTower if I call p.foo() this will be p, but then... when is not bound to p?

Comment: Isn't all this covered in [How does the this keyword work?](/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: If you call `p.foo()`, then the fact that the code starts with `p.` will cause `this` to equal `p`. This is not locked in ahead of time, it's just a result of the way you called it. Change the code to `const temp = p.foo; temp()`, and `this` will no longer be `p`.

Comment: What you remember is wrong. JS never worked that way.

Comment: @NicholasTower ah yes. Now I remember how it works. Thanks. Getting old. Closing

Comment: `this` can best be understood as a fixed-named argument with index -1 which is passed when the call is made together with the "normal" arguments (if any). Some special rules apply, but if you understand this part, you get a long way.